# How to Open jQuery UI accordion panel via an external link / URL with hash in tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use jquery to show accordions in tabs.The accordion in the tabs work. I would like to call up individual accordions via hash-url (open state). I tried that with the jquery code below. Unfortunately that doesn't work. A URL like domain.de/page/#1 generates the anchor link, but the accoedion ist not opended in active state. Here is my code:

```
   <div class="row">
            <div id="tabs" class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="auswahl-nav auswahl-nav-white">
                    <li><a href="#show-all" class="active">Show all</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#carrier-billing" class="active">Carrier Billing</a></li>
                ....
                </ul>

          <div id="show-all" class="acc-item">
            <!-- All items for carrier billing in "Show all" tab -->
            <div id="accordion">
               <h3 class="acc-header"><a href="#1" id="1"><headline></a></h3>
               <div class="acc-content"> <content>
               <br>
               </div>
            </div><!-- #accordion -->
          </div><!-- #carrier-billing.acc-item -->


             <div id="mobile-messaging" class="acc-item">
               <div id="accordion1">
                    <h3 class="acc-header"><a href="#1" id="1"><headline></a></h3>
                    <div class="acc-content"> <content>
                    <br>
                    </div>
               </div> 
             </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

To trigger the accordion and to generate a #hash URL i use the following code:

```
  $(function() {
    $('#show-all #accordion').accordion({
     disabled: true
    });
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var anchor = $('a[href$="'+hash+'"]');
    if (anchor.length > 0){
    anchor.click();
    }
  });

  $(function() {
   $('#carrier-billing #accordion').accordion({
  disabled: true
});
var hash = window.location.hash;
var anchor = $('a[href$="'+hash+'"]');
if (anchor.length > 0){
anchor.click();
}
  });
```

The hash url doesn't work. I would like to have something to open an accordion: domain.de/page/#1
I did the same thing in my opinion as in the instructions: https://www.digiplek.nl/open-jquery-ui-panel-via-an-external-link-url-with-hash.html#1

Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to have multiple elements with the ID `accordion`. This is invalid HTML and may be related to your problem.

Comment: Hi, i changed IDs. But cant call the anchorlink domian.de/page/#1 I think this has something to do by accodions within tabs?